# Calculate Percentages In a column

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have an Excel worksheet with information in a format much like a test:

```
Choice     Chosen        Percentage
A 
B 
C 
D 
TOTAL 
False 
True 
TOTAL
```

The Chosen column gives how many times each choice was selected, and the Total row totals for the corresponding question.  I need a way to quickly find the Percentage each was selected (Chosen/Total) but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: will there ever be blank values in between questions and the totals in column A?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need VBA for that. It's just a simple formula if I understand the question. Assuming these are headers and it starts at cell A1, then Percentage for column b (choice was A) will be like =B2/$F2 and you format the column as percentage type.

Note the $F is an absolute reference to F so that when you fill down, it always points to row F (total row) but the column number changes as it should.

Comment: Yes, it is a simple formula but I have 100 questions each with 2-5 choices - all of which need the percentage calculated.  What I would like is a way to do it in one swell swoop so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the total that is calculated is in the Chosen column as well.

Comment: But...a formula DOES calculate it all at once. You just fill down (it's one click). Is this not a normal excel sheet? I have done similar things with sheets with a LOT more options than 100. You know you can just pivot to get those totals and percentages, right? Are you concerned because of your subtotals? Do you have control over the format of the data in the sheet?

Comment: well each question is not taken the same number of times so the total is specific to each question/group of choices.

Comment: Do you have control of the output? If you add the question number as the first column and omit the subtotals, a pivot table will do this whole thing for you.

Comment: alphabets are columns, numbers are rows

Answer (score 0):

I am writing code on the fly and in this window itself, so you'd need to watch out for errors. Also, you'll need to put in code for psuedo code

```
dim currRow as integer
dim frs as boolean
firstRow = 1
frs = false
range("A1").select
<loop over column A until you reach a blank value>
  If selection.value == "Choice" then 
    ' move to next row, nothing to see here
  else if not selection.value == "Total" then
    if frs = false then 
      firstRow = selection.row
      frs = true
    endif
  else if selection.value = "Total" then
    frs = false
    dim i as integer
    for i = firstRow to selection.row -1
      range("C" + cstr(i)).formula = "=B"+ cstr(1)+"/B" + cstr (selection.row) ' or something to that effect
    next
  end if
  Selection.cells(2,1).select ' selects the next cell vertically
end loop
```

I am using frs to signify 'firstrow' has been set